# Swift: How to prevent window to show up on launch?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am writing a macOS Cocoa application with Swift and I don't know how to prevent, that the main window shows up on application startup. I want to check first, if there is a new version available on the server: if there is one, a spash screen should appear. I don't know how to accomplish this and couldn't find good information too. I also don't know how to get rid of the windows standard buttons like for closing the window. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check settings of your main window in Xcode. There are some checkboxes which control window buttons and other settings in Attributes inspector.

[image]

You can disable or enable them programmatically when you accessing Window object.

For example you can implement this approach in WindowController like this:

```
class WindowController: NSWindowController {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        window!.styleMask &= ~NSClosableWindowMask
    }

}
```

Previously you need to add your custom WindowController class to window controller object in storyboard (Identity inspector tab).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now I found the attributes inspector...
But where can I find the window object?

Comment: It should be in your ApplicationDelegate class in default configuration.

Comment: Do you mean the following variable in the class AppDelegate?
`@IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!`

If write "window" and type a point, no sense box appears.
How can I work with it?

Comment: Yes, if this variable is related to your window. I can't say that for sure without seeing your code. I've added example in the answer, for default Xcode project template. Hope this helps.